# Git Reverting a big PUSHed file

Tags: git, push, revert

I accidentally added (git add *) a big file (200+ MB) to a git repository. I commit the changes and pushed it.

When I tried to pull changes on some other copy, it was taking too long. I canceled the pull, removed the file (git rm file), commit, and pushed again. But it's still taking too long to pulling on other working copy.

So, how to remove it completely from the main repo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object is still in the repo, and the remotes are trying to download this object when they pull.

This [recipe at github](http://help.github.com/removing-sensitive-data/) should help remove the object from the repo's history.

Comment: Although it took a while re-writing the history but IT WORKS. Thanks.

Comment: If git-filter-branch takes a long time to rewrite your history, you probably want to try The BFG- http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/ - it's 10-50x faster at removing unwanted data (ie big files).